# summing a series of inputs not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to keep users from entering a number over their budget by summing the series of inputs (one for each month) and comparing their sum with the budget number on the blur event which is stored in a hidden input field named topLimit.

Since I have to do this several times on the page, I created a function to which I pass the name of the class assigned to a specific set of monthly inputs. For testing I am alerting the result and I get "undefined." Is it that I can't use a function parameter as a selector? Is it something else?

```
function TotalInputs(name){
    var numb = 0;
    $('.'+name).each(function(e){
         numb = numb + parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    return numb;
} // end TotalInputs function

(function() {
    var ttlFields = 0;

    $(document).on('blur', '.eSAM', function(e){
      var upperLimit = $('input[name="topLimit"]').val();
      ttlFields = TotalInputs('eSAM');
      alert(ttlFields);
    }); // end eSAM blur
})();
```

Comment: `TotalInputs` doesn't have access to the `numb` that you defined as `0`, therefore `undefined + 5.5` is `NaN`.

Comment: var ttlFields = 0;
var numb = 0;
must be out of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you make `var numb = 0;` a global variable or place your `TotalInputs` inside your anonymous function.

So, do it like this:

```
(function() {
    var ttlFields = 0;
    var numb = 0;

    function TotalInputs(name){
        $('.'+name).each(function(e){
             numb = numb + parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        return numb;
    } // end TotalInputs function

    $(document).on('blur', '.eSAM', function(e){
      var upperLimit = $('input[name="topLimit"]').val();
      ttlFields = TotalInputs('eSAM');
      alert(ttlFields);
    }); // end eSAM blur
})();
```

Or like this:

```
var numb = 0;

function TotalInputs(name){
    $('.'+name).each(function(e){
         numb = numb + parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    return numb;
} // end TotalInputs function

(function() {
    var ttlFields = 0;

    $(document).on('blur', '.eSAM', function(e){
      var upperLimit = $('input[name="topLimit"]').val();
      ttlFields = TotalInputs('eSAM');
      alert(ttlFields);
    }); // end eSAM blur
})();
```